# mysql-python install with Percona

Tags: python, mysql, percona

I have Percona Server installed on CentOS. I want to install mysql-python but I am getting this error
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

There is no such file for Percona Server. How can I install mysql-python to connect to Percona mysql ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get mysql_config by running:

```
yum install Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel
```

Once you have this, go ahead and install mysql-python:

```
yum install mysql-python
```

I searched a lot of google before I found this here at:
http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/11038-mysql-config-sysbench-percona-xtradb-cluster

Comment: in my case: yum install Percona-Server-devel-56